# Regex to check Wi-Fi Phys Mode

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression to check whether the Wi-Fi Phys Mode data is   valid. The data should start with "802.11" and could be followed by a/b/g/n/ac or a combination of these. The current checking is like "^802.11[a-zA-Z|]", but I want to make it more accurate.

The accepted examples is like

```
"802.11" 
"802.11a"
"802.11n"
"802.11ac"
"802.11a|n"
"802.11a|n|ac"
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will `802.11a|a`, `802.11a|g|a` be valid? What is the regex flavor?

Comment: 802.11a|a should not be valid but 802.11a|ac should be. The combination should not be duplicated. I am using python for scripting. Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^802\.11(?!(?:.*\|)?([abgn]|ac)\b.*\|\1(?=\||$))(?:(?:[abgn]|ac)(?:\|(?:[abgn]|ac))*)?$
```

In Python, use a raw string literal for it to work properly,

```
pattern = r'^802\.11(?!(?:.*\|)?([abgn]|ac)\b.*\|\1(?=\||$))(?:(?:[abgn]|ac)(?:\|(?:[abgn]|ac))*)?$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKU9Ds/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `802\.11` - `802.11` substring
- `(?!(?:.*\|)?([abgn]|ac)\b.*\|\1(?=\||$))` - a negative lookahead that looks for its pattern immediately to the right of the current location and if it matches, the whole match is failed:

  - `(?:.*\|)?` - an optional substring made of any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then a `|`
  - `([abgn]|ac)` - Group 1: `a`, `b`, `g`, `n` or `ac`
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\|` - a `|`
  - `\1` - the same value as captured into Group 1
  - `(?=\||$)` = `(?![^|])` - there must be end of string or `|` right after
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group:

  - `(?:[abgn]|ac)` - `a`, `b`, `g`, `n` or `ac`
  - `(?:\|` - an inner grouping matching a `|` and...

    - `(?:[abgn]|ac)` - `a`, `b`, `g`, `n` or `ac`...
  - )*` - zero or more times
- `)?` - end of the optional group
- `$` - end of string.